# ffmpeg mjpeg stream record as hls hls_time not working

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I am trying to save mjpeg stream to hls using following command

```
ffmpeg -f mjpeg  -i http://192.168.1.145:8081   -f hls -hls_list_size 4 -hls_time 2 -hls_flags delete_segments ./live.m3u8
```

And the output file is created but there are too much latency happening with camera live and created hls playlist. I tried to make the segment duration to 2 second  by `-hls_time 2` but in output it seems 10 second.

**live.m3u8**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2
#EXTINF:10.000000,
live2.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
live3.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
live4.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
live5.ts
#EXTINF:3.320000,
live6.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

How can I record the stream by reducing the latency on hls playlist. I am getting the stream from RaspberryPi camera running [motioneyeos](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos/wiki)

Comment: Your current command is re-encoding video to H.264 with a default keyframe interval (250 frames for x264 encoder). Add `-force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, it works fine, and the latency reduced to 10 second is there any way to reduce to 5 second.